# C# Recursive Search an array of Objects.parent_id for value, then search those and so on till none left

Tags: c#, arrays, object, search

Looking for a solution to find an `object.id` and get all the `parent_id`'s in an array of objects, and then set `object.missed = true`.
`Object.id`, and Object `parent_id`. If the object doesn't have a `parent_id`, `parent_id = id`.

I know how to do it for one level of `parent_id`'s. How can I go unlimited levels deep? Below is the code I have for searching the 1 level.

```
public class EPlan 
{
    public int id;
    public int parent_id;
    public bool is_repeatable;
    public bool missed;
}

EPlan[] plans = Array.FindAll(eventsPlan, item => item.parent_id == event_id);
foreach (EPlan plan in plans)
{
    plan.missed = true;
    plan.is_repeatable = false;
}
```

I'm trying to search for `event_id` an `int`. So I search all of the `object.id`'s for `event_id`. Once I find `object.id == event_id`. I need to set `object.is_repeatable = false` and `object.missed = true`.

Then I need to search all of the objects.parent_id for current object.id (event_id). Change all of those object to the same as above. 
Then I need to check all of those `object.id`'s against all of the `object.parent_id`'s and do the same to those. Like a tree affect. 1 event was missed, and any of the events that are parented to that event need to be set as missed as well.

So far, all I can do is get 1 level deep, or code multiple foreach loops in. But it could be 10 or more levels deep. So that doesn't make sense.

Any help is appreciated. There has to be a better way that the multiple loops.

Comment: I not certain how I can explain this any more clearly. But I'll try again. I've edited the question. Thank you for looking, I think I've explained better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too was confused by the question, save for the one line you said:

> 1 event was missed, and any of the events that are parented to that event need to be set as missed as well.

With that in mind, I suggest the following code will do what you're looking for. Each time you call the method, it will find all of the objects in the array that match the `ID` and set the event as `Missed` and `Is_Repeatable` appropriately.

It also keeps a running list of the `Parent_ID`'s it found during this scan. Once the loop is finished it will call itself, using the list of parent id values instead of the passed in list of events ids it just used. That is the trick that makes the recursion work here.

To start the process off, you call the method with the single event ID you did for 1-level search.

```
findEvents(new List<string>{event_id}, eventsPlan);

private void findEvents(List<int> eventIDs, EPlan[] eventsPlan)
{
    foreach (int eventID in eventIDs)
    {
        EPlan[] plans = Array.FindAll(eventsPlan, item => item.parent_id == eventID);
        List<int> parentIDs = new List<int>();
        foreach (EPlan plan in plans)
        {
            plan.missed = true;
            plan.is_repeatable = false;
            parentIDs.Add(plan.parent_id);
        }
        if (parentIDs.Count > 0)
           findEvents(parentIDs, eventsPlan);
    }
}
```

I also recommend that if you have the chance to reengineer this code to not use arrays, but a Generic Collection (like `List<EPlan>`) you can avoid the performance penalty this code has because it's building new arrays in memory each time you call the `Array.FindAll` method. Using the Generic Collection, or even using old-school `foreach` loop will work faster when processing a lot of data here.

**Update 1:**
To answer your question about how you might go about this using a Generic Collection instead:

```
private void findEventsAsList(List<int> eventIDs, List<EPlan> eventsPlans)
{
    List<int> parentIDs = new List<int>();
    foreach (EPlan plan in eventsPlans.Where(p => eventIDs.Contains(p.parent_id)))
    {
       plan.missed = true;
       plan.is_repeatable = false;
       parentIDs.Add(plan.parent_id);
    }
    findEventsAsList(parentIDs, eventsPlan);
}
```

Comment: How would you do this if the EPlan was a list?

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I'm going to switch it to a List instead. I have PHP background and use a lot of arrays. Lists make more sense.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me!

Comment: I'm getting a stack overflow error on 
parentIDs.Add(plan.parent_id);
and 
findEventsAsList(parentIDs, eventsPlan);
So I added a if (parentIDs.Count > 0) on the findEventsAsList.
But now I get a stack overflow on 
foreach (EPlan plan in eventsPlans.Where(p => eventIDs.Contains(p.parent_id)))
I'm lost on how to fix that.

Comment: It's currently only got 2 levels deep so I'm not sure why it would give it only on the second run.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: I'll accept the answer, but still having the stack overflow issue On
foreach (EPlan plan in eventsPlans.Where(p => eventIDs.Contains(p.parent_id)))

Comment: Its saying that's the first one. Then it points to 
`findEventsAsList(parentIDs, eventsPlan);`
and repeats this till truncated.

Comment: Changing `findEventsAsList(parentIDs, eventsPlan);` to `try {findEventsAsList(parentIDs, eventsPlan);}catch{}` Seems to solve the issue for me.

Comment: Having an error trap doesn't actually mean that the program is working, though. If you want more help, I would suggest creating a .Net Fiddle that demonstrates the program.